# WYSIWYG Text Editor Not Triggering TextArea Text

Tags: php, jquery, wysiwyg, text-editor, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I am using Responsive-WYSIWYG-Text-Editor-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-LineControl-Editor
But when form is posted textarea value is null and one more thing i have used Required Attribute on TextArea But still form gets posted without entering text in textarea. Below is my code -

**HTML CODE**

```
<textarea name="Content" id="txtEditor" class="form-control" placeholder="Have a New Face To Slap! Post Here" maxlength=250 required></textarea>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
    //I am Enable TextEditor On TextArea Click
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtEditor").click(function(){
                $("#txtEditor").Editor();

        });
```

The Following Div Is Generated By WYSIWYG editor that holds the values entered in Textarea

```
<div class="Editor-editor" contenteditable="true" style="overflow: auto;">Text Area value&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used WYSIWYG Editor But according to your problem i have a solution available for you .

Solution : You Div With Class Editor-editor is having Value that you type in WYSIWYG Editor and you need to put that to your  But yes we can easily do that using jquery class selector See Code Below -

You Must Be having a  Tag With Submit Button So We are trying to Copy Contents from  To

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="Submit" onclick=" $('#txtEditor').val($('.Editor-editor').text());">Post</button>
```

And That is Enough Now Your  On which you have placed WYSIWYG editor Will have Text that you typed in WYSIWYG Editor

Comment: Let me try this solution

Comment: Thanks I think this will help me it is posting value now

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed before when using some editors that the editor is actually created separately to the textarea you have created with a different ID. It might be worth checking with a tool like firebug that the editor is definitely using the ID "txtEditor"

Comment: yes it using txtEditor and adding a div next to textarea but is there any method that textarea contains that text

Comment: a bug in the editor? If you're looking for a good wysiwyg editor i'd recommend tinymce - https://www.tinymce.com/